# Client Side Validation of a User Control that is not Visible on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have created a user control that has some custom client side validation.  I am embedding the Javascript via RegisterStartupScript, and passing information to the validation via RegisterExpandoAttribute.  However, the user control is not visible on PageLoad and when I use document.getElementById, I get null values.

Here is my current code:

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript; 
            Type cstype = this.GetType(); 
            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "ValidatorType")) 
            { 
                String DateValidator; 
                DateValidator = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"; 
                DateValidator += "function ValidateDate(source, args) {\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   var ddDay = document.getElementById(source.day);\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   var day = ddDay.selectedIndex;\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   var ddMonth = document.getElementById(source.month);\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   var month = ddMonth.selectedIndex;\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   var ddYear = document.getElementById(source.year);\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   var year = ddYear.selectedIndex;\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   if (day == 0 || month == 0 || year == 0)\n"; 
                DateValidator += "      args.IsValid = false;\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   else\n"; 
                DateValidator += "      args.IsValid = true;\n"; 
                DateValidator += "   }\n"; 
                DateValidator += "</script>"; 
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "ValidatorType", DateValidator); 
            } 

            cs.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "month", ddMonth.ClientID); 
            cs.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "day", ddDay.ClientID, false); 
            cs.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "year", ddYear.ClientID, false); 
    }
```

The errors that I receive are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'month' of null 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of null
```

Answer (score 1):

The control which is not visible in server side does not come in html on client generated by server. So It should be null. Make it invisible hidden using javascript and make it visible again when required using javascript.

The script should execute after rendering on controls.

**Hidding a server control on client**

```
document.getElementById('<%= pnlMail.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

**Hidding a HTML control on client**

```
document.getElementById('htmlControlID').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Get your place holder on browser and hide it with javascript. Suppose your place holder has id pnlMain then you can hide it by document.getElementById('<%= pnlMail.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

A more "server-side" approach would be to set the value on the server, then you aren't reliant on javascript.  ASCX:

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uxToHide" />
```

Code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uxToHide.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
```

Using PlaceHolders adds a little complexity, but it's not too bad.  ASCX:

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="uxToHide" runat="server" />
```

Code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Style["display"] = "none";
        uxToHide.Controls.Add(tb);

        ShowChildren(uxToHide);
    }

    public static void HideChildren(Control container)
    {
        if (container == null || container.Controls == null || container.Controls.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
        {
            if (c is WebControl)
            {
                ((WebControl)c).Style["display"] = "none";
            }
            HideChildren(c);
        }
    }

    public static void ShowChildren(Control container)
    {
        if (container == null || container.Controls == null || container.Controls.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
        {
            if (c is WebControl)
            {
                WebControl wc = (WebControl)c;
                if (wc.Style["display"] == "none")
                {
                    wc.Style.Remove("display");
                }
            }
            ShowChildren(c);
        }
    }
```